# PHP if statment combined with html

Tags: php, html

It's possible to combine a **php** if statement if i have for example this code:

```
<div id="contentArea">classic content field</div>
```

This id is html, and my question is, can i do a if statement with **php** if my **html id** is not empty...

for example so:

```
if(!empty('MY_HTML_ID')) { echo '<div id="contentArea"></div>'; }
```

Comment: The HTML id is hardcoded is your example, so the answer would be "you don't need a condition, the id will never be empty". Please show the real thing.

Comment: did u use php tags? (<?php ?>)

Comment: I dont think youcan do it using PHP, but you can do it using javascript/jQuery

Comment: Your example code will work, have you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried, because i know that this can't work, this was on examply to make a good example what i need... but this with jquery is good...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I work with a template system, {some_text_field}, and i can't do some request if is not empty... my idea was to do a if request, if not empty then not write rest of html code

Comment: @MirkoSimic, see the update, could be useful maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why PHP? You should use something like that (jquery example):

```
if( $('#MY_HTML_ID').is(':empty') ) { }
```

or:

```
if( $('#MY_HTML_ID:empty').length ) { }
```

**Edit:** If you are using a template system, you can also check the variable inside of the div, for example with this logic:

```
<div>
    <% if $MyDinner %>
        You can do the request
    <% else %>
        You can't, because the variable $MyDinner has no value
    <% end_if %>
</div>
```

Comment: This code part was helpfull for me, i don't know why, but i have become 1000 ideas how to solve... :) thanke you, thanke you...